# Wi-Fi Sabrent PCI-8021N Linux Debian Jessie _x86_64 using ralink firmware/desktop

Tags: networking, wifi

I've been trying since Thursday to get a sabrent card to come up and show what wifi networks are available. I'm in midtown Atlanta...so seems there should be 1 or 2 networks showing.

The card's power light is on.

I tried running:

```
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

in the terminal which didn't give any errors but dmesg shows:

```
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
```

How can I make `wlan0` ready? ....or am I going at this all wrong?

Comment: Many cards require firmware that Debian does not redistribute, probably because of unclear licensing.  Use `dmesg` to see what happens when the card is first detected and see if there is a message about firmware failing to load.  That'll give you a name,  and then you can go on a google hunt to find someplace to get it.  Often a chip company's site.  Even if that's not it, checking `dmesg` is a good thing to do